# Simple web scrapping using javascript to pull all contents on div element

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I want to web scrap all contents of element `<section class="landing-page">` from  [this page](https://www.itftennis.com/en/tournament/w60-rio-de-janeiro/bra/2022/w-itf-bra-09a-2022/acceptance-list/).

I am looking for simple java-script method to do the job but i have not found any example so far from where i can learn rather most of example are pointing to third scrapping tools

I am not even sure if this is purely possible using java script only without third party tools NodeJS etc

Comment: Show us your efforts: what have you tried until now, to determine if possible or not?

Comment: I have been looking for example based on pure JS but not found 1, what i see is webscrapping using Silinium, papeteer, and other examples use NodeJS or python etc.. So i dont have a pointer where i can start to learn.. So no code from my side as i a still search for pure js based example. for this reason as i asked if its possible with pure JS. you can point me in right direction..

Comment: Well, NodeJS is not a `3rd party` tool: it is JS Runtime. You need to anchor your code somewhere, be it a NodeJS scaffold, or something similar. That data is easy to scrape - you just need to GET the [API endpoint](https://www.itftennis.com/tennis/api/TournamentApi/GetAcceptanceList?tournamentKey=w-itf-bra-09a-2022&circuitCode=WT) and analyse the JSON response. But I doubt you will receive a response, considering the lack of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus, Appreciate your response, i was looking for easy way out with JS so that i can copy all elements inside div and then show them on a different web page with custom css.. this json is complex for me it has lot of nested nodes and i am not sure if it changes as tournament progresses. so most easy to me seemed simple js web-scrapping which doesn't seem to be there

Comment: If you'd be open to a python solution, it's really easy to get that data - that JSON response can be read with Pandas and further analysed etc. Nonetheless, I hope you'll get a response.